# Chat Program: Client to Server Connectivity Issue

Tags: java, sockets, networking, serversocket, packet

### Project Summary

- **Goal:** A simple application that connects a client to a server hosted on one computer and allows that client from another computer to send chat messages to everyone on that specified server.
- Class ClientWindow: Runs an application that prompts the user to enter in a server ID and port. Once entered, it starts the chat program.

### Problem:

For some reason unknown to me, the chat program ONLY works when connecting to a server that you've created on your own computer. Other clients from other computers cannot connect to that server.

**Possible reasons for problem:**

- I might have incorrectly constructed the server's receiving/sending sockets
- I might have incorrectly constructed the client's receiving/sending sockets
- Something is getting wonky in the packets being sent between client and server
- Somehow IP addresses for the sockets are being defined incorrectly

Here is the code for the chat program.

#### Start server

This class starts the server on the specified port. (12348 in this instance)

```
package server;

public class ChatServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Server.start(12348);

        
    }

}
```

#### Server

This is the class that creates the server and listens for client connections and messages.

```
package server;

import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Server {

    private static DatagramSocket socket;
    private static boolean running;

    private static int ClientID; // Ensures that no two users have the same client ID
    private static ArrayList<ClientInfo> clients = new ArrayList<ClientInfo>();

    public static void start(int port) {

        try {

            socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Application Starting...");
            running = true;
            listen();
            System.out.println("Server started on port: " + port);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed somewhere");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static void broadcast(String message) {

        for (ClientInfo info : clients) {
            send(message, info.getAddress(), info.getPort());
        }

    }

    private static void send(String message, InetAddress address, int port) {

        try {

            message += "\\e";
            byte[] data = message.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, address, port);
            socket.send(packet);
            System.out.println("Sent message to," + address.getHostAddress() + ":" + port);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static void listen() {
        
        Thread listenThread = new Thread("ChatProgram Listener Thread") {
            
            public void run() {
            
                try {
                     while(running) {
                         
                         byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                         DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length); 
                         socket.receive(packet);
                         
                         String message = new String(data);
                         //Identify where the end of the message is
                         message = message.substring(0, message.indexOf("\\e"));
                         
                         //Manage message
                         if(!isCommand(message, packet)) {
                            broadcast(message);
                         }
                        
                     }
                    
                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            
        }; listenThread.start();
        
    }

    /*
     * SERVER COMMAND LIST 
     * \con:[name] -> Connects client to server 
     * \dis:[id] -> Disconnects client from server
     * 
     * 
     * 
     */

    private static boolean isCommand(String message, DatagramPacket packet) {

        if (message.startsWith("\\con:")) {
            // RUN CONNECTION CODE

            String name = message.substring(message.indexOf(":") + 1);
            clients.add(new ClientInfo(name, ClientID++, packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort()));
            broadcast("User " + name + " Connected!");

            return true;
        }

        if (message.startsWith("\\dis:")) {
            // RUN DISCONNECTION CODE
            
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void stop() {

        running = false;

    }
}
```

#### Start Client

Starts the client application.

```
package client;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Frame;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class ClientWindow {

    private JFrame frmChatProgram;
    private JTextField textField;
    private static JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    private Client client;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    ClientWindow window = new ClientWindow();
                    window.frmChatProgram.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    
    public ClientWindow() throws UnknownHostException {
        initialize();
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name:");
        String servIp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter server IP address:");
        String port = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter server port:");
        
        int parsedPort = Integer.parseInt(port);
        
        //InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        
        client = new Client(name, servIp, parsedPort);
    }

    private void initialize() {
        
        
        frmChatProgram = new JFrame();
        frmChatProgram.setResizable(false);
        frmChatProgram.setTitle("Chat Program");
        frmChatProgram.setBounds(100, 100, 620, 446);
        frmChatProgram.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmChatProgram.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frmChatProgram.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        frmChatProgram.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        textArea.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        
        
        textArea.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        frmChatProgram.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        frmChatProgram.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));
        
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(40);
        
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Send");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(e ->{
            
            if (!textField.getText().equals("")) {
                
                client.send(textField.getText());
                textField.setText("");
                
            }
            
            
        });
        panel.add(btnNewButton);
        
        frmChatProgram.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
    }
    
    public static void printToConsole(String message) {
        
        textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + message + "\n");
        
    }

}
```

#### Client

Creates a client connection and listener for that client

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import server.ClientInfo;

public class Client {

    private DatagramSocket socket;
    private InetAddress address;
    private int port;
    private boolean running;
    private String name;
    
    public Client(String name, String address, int port) {
        try {
            this.name = name;
            this.address = InetAddress.getByName(address);
            this.port = port;
            socket = new DatagramSocket();
            socket.connect(this.address, port);
            
            running = true;
            listen();
            send("\\con:" + name);

            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void send(String message) {

        try {
            
            if (!message.startsWith("\\")) {
            message = name+": "+message;
                
                
            }

            message += "\\e";
            byte[] data = message.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, address, port);
            socket.send(packet);
            System.out.println("Sent message to," + address.getHostAddress() + ":" + port);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void listen() {

        Thread listenThread = new Thread("ChatProgram Listener Thread") {

            public void run() {

                try {
                    while (running) {

                        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
                        socket.receive(packet);

                        String message = new String(data);
                        // Identify where the end of the message is
                        message = message.substring(0, message.indexOf("\\e"));

                        // Manage message
                        if (!isCommand(message, packet)) {
                            
                            ClientWindow.printToConsole(message);
                            
                        }

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }; listenThread.start();

    }

    private static boolean isCommand(String message, DatagramPacket packet) {

        if (message.startsWith("\\con:")) {
            // RUN CONNECTION CODE

            return true;
        }

        if (message.startsWith("\\dis:")) {
            // RUN DISCONNECTION CODE

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    
    
    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are asking about the possible reasons that your code is not be working:

> 1)  I might have incorrectly constructed the server's receiving/sending sockets.

That is possible.  You should be able to tell that by using a debugger to examine the packets on the server side.

> 2)  I might have incorrectly constructed the client's receiving/sending sockets

Ditto ...

> 3) Something is getting wonky in the packets being sent between client and server

This is the most likely:

- It could be a packet-level routing problem ... though that is likely to have broader effects.
- It could be firewall issue
- It could be an MTU issue
- It could even be a broken switch, etc.

> 4) Somehow IP addresses for the sockets are being defined incorrectly

That is possible.

---

There are various things you could do to diagnose / eliminate the various possibilities.  But this is not really a StackOverflow problem.